# filtering data within a correlated matrix

Tags: r, correlation, bioconductor, r-corrplot, ggcorrplot

I have an data.frame, compare the X and Y axes, and then I get N results, and I need to generate a graphic, be `ggcorplot` or `correlationplot`, but I wanted to make a filter for the chart, where only values above 0 will be included in the graph

I have already tried ,

```
dataCorrealtion[dataCorrelation > 0] <- ""
```

but the graph doesn't accept an empty value, and I can't put a fake value

I hope to be able to generate a graph without values that are less than 0

Comment: Try to assign `NA` instead of `""` like  `dataCorrealtion[dataCorrelation > 0] <- NA`

Comment: hey friend, NA or NAN?

Comment: I tried NaN but retorned this error
`NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)`

Comment: `data <- c(-5,-1,4,-2,0,1)` . and  `data[data<=0] <- NA` gives `NA NA  4 NA NA  1` . By the way, I have just realized, if you want to have values which are greater than zero, you need to assign `NA` for the values less than or equal to zero (`<=`) .

Comment: yes, I understood friend, but the problem is when I generate the graphs

Comment: If you run `plot(data[data<=0])` , only two values will be shown on the graph.What is the problem then?

Comment: Well when I run this `ggcorrplot(dataCorrelation[data<=0], hc.order = TRUE, type = "lower",lab = TRUE)` I recive a blank chart